# establecer el path de un fichero pdf descargado desde un link

Tags: python, pdf, descarga, tab

Mi problema es el siguiente: Yo llego a una página dónde hay un link que sirve para recoger un fichero pdf. El tema es que al pinchar sobre el link, Chrome me abre una pestaña nueva donde parece que va a verse el fichero pdf, pero inmediatamente la cierra y procede a descargar el fichero en el directorio por defecto de descargas con un nombre estándar. Eso es un problema para mí, porque estamos usando multithreading y podría ser que otro hilo, tras generar otro fichero, siguiendo el mismo código descargase allí otro fichero con el mismo nombre pero con contenido diferente. Por eso no me sirve ir al directorio de descargas y recoger el último fichero descargado allí, porque no podría estar seguro de que correspondiese a mi hilo.

Una solución sería poder descargar el fichero en un directorio determinado. Eso no puedo hacerlo porque a lo largo del código debo repetir la operación varias veces y, por lo que sé, sólo se puede establecer una vez el directorio de descarga para cada instancia del driver.

Otra sería conseguir que el fichero del link no se descargase sino que se abriese en la pestaña que se abre (y que no se cerrase inmediatamente, claro).

No sé como programar ninguna de las dos. ¿Puede alguien ayudarme? Muchas gracias,,

Answer (score 0):

de momento ya tengo la segunda opción. Era tan sencillo como cambiar

```
'download. prompt_for_download': False,
```

por
'download. prompt_for_download': True,